# For what $\alpha$ and $\beta$ values does $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}$ $\frac {| x|^{\alpha}| y|^{\beta}}{\ x^4 + y^4 }$ goes to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

For what $\alpha$ and $\beta$ values does  $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}$ $\frac {| x|^{\alpha}| y|^{\beta}}{\ x^4 + y^4 }$ goes to $0$ ?

Only for $\alpha >0$ and $\beta >0$

Comment: Can you conclude by the hint given? consider three cases $$\alpha + \beta-4>0$$ $$\alpha + \beta-4=0$$ $$\alpha + \beta-4<0$$ to conclude

Comment: show your work to conlude the OP or ask for further clarifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use that $$x^4+y^4\geq 2x^2y^2$$

Comment: should I use that inequality without absolute value? I mean, can I reach the $\frac{x^{\alpha - 2} y^{\beta -2}}{2}$ expression without using that inequality without absolute value? Is that correct?

Comment: @puradrogasincortar and thus how do you conclude from here? $$\frac{x^{\alpha - 2} y^{\beta -2}}{2}$$ and for $x$ or $y<0$ are exponentiation defined? You are loosing a lot of details here to conclude properly

Comment: you must write $$\frac{|x|^{\alpha}|y|^{\beta}}{|x|^2|y|^2}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner and then how we conclude from here?$$\frac{|x|^{\alpha}|y|^{\beta}}{|x|^2|y|^2}$$ what about for $\beta=1$ and $\alpha=4$ for example? what is the general result for $\alpha$,$\beta$>0? I'm not sure that the asker has completely understood what is going here.

Comment: it is $$|x|^{2-\alpha}|y|^{\beta-2}$$ and this tends only to zero if $$\alpha>2,\beta>2$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner and what about $\alpha=4$ and $\beta=1$?

Comment: then we get $$\frac{1}{|x|^2|y|}$$ how should this tends to Zero for $x,y$ tends to Zero? is is impossible!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Maybe you mean? $$|x|^{\alpha-2}|y|^{\beta-2}$$

Comment: yes and the question was above $$\alpha=4,\beta=1$$

Comment: I think (...think) I solved it correctly. I got the expression $\frac {| x|^{\alpha-2}| y|^{\beta -2}}{ 2 }$, from the previous inequality. Then I  have $\frac {| x|^{\alpha-2}| y|^{\beta -2}}{ 2 } \le \frac {||(x,y)||^{\alpha + \beta -4}}{ 2 }$ and this goes to 0 for $\alpha + \beta \gt 4$.
Then for $\alpha + \beta \le 4$ I used the sucesion $x_k = (1/k, 1/k)$ and this one told me the limit won't go to 0 for $\alpha + \beta \le 4$.

Comment: it sounds good!!

Comment: @puradrogasincortar ok now the result is correct, I don't recognize this step $$\frac {| x|^{\alpha-2}| y|^{\beta -2}}{ 2 } \le \frac {||(x,y)||^{\alpha + \beta -4}}{ 2 }$$ could you clarify please?

Comment: basically, the absolute value of a coordinate is less or equal to the norm of the vector. Using that you can group $|x|$  and $|y|$ together.

Comment: mmhhh with these coefficient this step is not so immediately clear to me, I think that polar coordinates are a better tool in this case also for this last step, by the way finally we have a correct result!

Comment: why do you think so?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Your hint is good starting point, the step used by the asker is not so clear in my opinion, thus I suggest for this finl step to use polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

By polar coordinates

$$\frac {| x|^{\alpha}| y|^{\beta}}{\ x^4 + y^4 } =\frac {r^{\alpha + \beta}| \cos \theta|^{\alpha}| \sin \theta|^{\beta}}{r^4( \cos^4\theta + \sin^4\theta) }
=r^{\alpha + \beta-4}\frac {  | \cos \theta|^{\alpha}| \sin \theta|^{\beta}}{  \cos^4\theta + \sin^4\theta}$$

then observe that $$\forall \theta \quad \cos^4\theta + \sin^4\theta\ge m>0$$